Why is detox build and tests running on Xcode 16 slower
Why are iOS Detox build times and iOS Detox test run times after updating Xcode 16 slower?
Here’s my setup on CircleCI with the same test cases:

Xcode: 15.3.0
Detox: 20.23.0
iOS Version: 17.4 (iPhone 15 Pro Max)

After updating to the following configuration:

Xcode: 16.1.0
Detox: 20.28.0
iOS Version: 18.1 (iPhone 16 Pro Max)

I noticed:

25% increase in iOS build time
131% increase in Detox test run time, with some timeout failures.

I also tested with Xcode 16.0.0 and iOS 17.5, which improved a bit, but the results are still:

19% slower iOS build time
26% slower Detox test run time

I tested just upgrading Detox to version 20.28.0 and kept the current setup with Xcode 15.3.0 and didn't notice any performance issues, only when running on Xcode 16+.


This seems to be related to CircleCI xcode 16 image.
https://discuss.circleci.com/t/xcode-16-performance-regression/52129
